# show border for the table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show border for the tooltip table. I tried using css code and using html border attribute, but tooltip table doesn't show the border.Please find fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/42/ .  When i mouseover on the image in the table, tooltip is displayed, i want to display border for the tooltip table.

Below is sample code:

```
<table class="tooltipTable" style="position:absolute;">
    <tr><td>row1 </td></tr>
    <tr><td>row2</td></tr>
</table>
```

jquery to show tooltip:

```
$(function () {
  $('.one').attr('title', $('.tooltipTable').remove().html());
  $(document).tooltip();
});
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, adding a css border to the tooltip itself? This works:

```
.ui-tooltip {
    border:1px solid #00c!important;
}
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Marventus/dz6ky3sm/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a 2px wide border on the selector `.ui-tooltip`

Check it out:
http://jsfiddle.net/0w9yo8x6/43/

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean a border for the tooltip or for the rows inside it? if you meant the rows inside it then see fiidle [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dz6ky3sm/2/)

you can add to your stylesheet.

```
   .ui-tooltip-content td{
    border:1px solid #00c!important;
}
```